# Set default value for "Who can see posts this app makes for you on your Facebook timeline"

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-apps, privacy, facebook-app-requests

How can I set default value of "Who can see posts this app makes for you on your Facebook timeline" to "Only me" on my app installation dialog? Is there a way to block it so that they users cannot change it to "friends"?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're using the ios sdk, you can use this to initialize the session:

```
- (id)initWithAppID:(NSString*)appID
    permissions:(NSArray*)permissions
    defaultAudience:(FBSessionDefaultAudience)defaultAudience
    urlSchemeSuffix:(NSString*)urlSchemeSuffix
    tokenCacheStrategy:(FBSessionTokenCachingStrategy*)tokenCachingStrategy;
```

The defaultAudience sets the audience for the posts. If you look in the SDK code, you can see the FBSessionDefaultAudience values. It's in FBSession.h. I'm using the 3.1 SDK.

Comment: Thanks. Do you know how to do it for desktop and android?

Comment: @Arturo Sorry, no. It's probably buried in the respective SDK's. You'll probably need to view the code, since the docs are rarely up to date.